# Travis CI cannot find packages in the pkg-config search path

Tags: r, travis-ci

I've recently started encountering the same errors on my various `R` packages updated after mid-December on Travis-CI (https://travis-ci.org/TGuillerme/). This is specially weird since for the three concerned packages, the changes were not any code change (only [comments changes](https://github.com/TGuillerme/dispRity/compare/e17aa98a540b...012bc4fd0218)) but Travis-CI seems now not able to install some packages (namely `magick` and `libgit2`) using a pretty simple `.yml` file runing the package and `codecov` for coverage:

```
language: r
warnings_are_errors: false

branches:
  only:
    - master
    - release
  except:
    - CRAN

# Code coverage
r_packages:
  - covr

after_success:
- Rscript -e 'library(covr); codecov(token = "5f041826-63f1-47fa-b4a8-9a32633f47fa")'
```

The error I get in this case (although it varies with the different packages) is with the `magick` package:

> ```
> ** package ‘magick’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> Package Magick++ was not found in the pkg-config search path.
> Perhaps you should add the directory containing `Magick++.pc'
> to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
> No package 'Magick++' found
> Using PKG_CFLAGS=
> Using PKG_LIBS=-lMagick++-6.Q16
> ```

[line 2625-2631](https://travis-ci.org/TGuillerme/dispRity/builds/466835127#L1563)

Along with one suspicious message prior to this:

> ```
> Unable to find the libgit2 library on this system. Building 'git2r'
> using the bundled source of the libgit2 library.
> ```

[line 1563-1564](https://travis-ci.org/TGuillerme/dispRity/builds/466835127#L1563)

Is there something obvious that I am missing? Is there a way to force Travis-CI to automatically install the the errored packages?

Again, this is specially weird to me since the running code changes committed do not differ since [last build running without errors](https://travis-ci.org/TGuillerme/dispRity/builds/465528891).

Comment: can you try specifying the r version, something I do like `r:
  - devel`

Comment: The version of R installed by Travis-CI is the latest by default I believe. In this specific case: `R version 3.5.1 (2018-12-12)` with `Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)` and `Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS`.

Comment: I've had a few issues with installing other packages on Travis, and was able to fix them by using the binaries: `r_binary_packages: - ncdf4`

Comment: @r_alanb It looks like your suggestion should be added as an answer; OP seems to have followed it and now has passing build on Travis CI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been able to fix similar issues by installing packages from their binaries.

The following might help in the .travis.yml:

```
r_binary_packages:
    - libgit2
    - magick
```

Comment: This worked the trick indeed! Thanks a lot for the fix suggestion!